# if $|f(x)-f(y)|\le |x-y|^{\sqrt 2}$ then is $f$ a constant function?

Tags: derivatives, exponentiation, irrational-numbers

if $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le |x-y|^{\sqrt{2}}$$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ ,then is f increasing ,decreasing or constant?

in my view ,it is clear that $|f(x)-f(y)|$ is not zero so it is not constant.
And since the rate of change is positive so the function would be increasing.Is my solution correct or wrong?

Comment: Your solution is incorrect, in particular the part you say is clearly non-zero.

Comment: So what is the solution? Would you please answer it?

Comment: For starters: Why do you say it's clear? Can you name a non-constant function that satisfies the inequality? As a hint for the solution, try computing the derivative of $f$.

Comment: There is a solution avoiding differentiability, available on several pages of the site. (Hint: Decompose the interval $(x,y)$ into $n$ subintervals, apply the hypothesis to each of these subintervals, let $n\to\infty$, collect the result that $f(x)=f(y)$.)

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1119422/27978 for example :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the more general case: $|f(x)-f(y)|\le |x-y|^{1+\varepsilon}$, with $\varepsilon>0$.

Then $f$ is differentiable with $f'=0$ because
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0} \left|\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}\right|
\le
\lim_{x\to x_0}|x-x_0|^{\varepsilon}
= 0
$$

So, $\sqrt2$ is a red herring. Its only relevant property is $\sqrt2>1$.